# Fetching data from local array of values using angular not working

Tags: java, php, angularjs, jsp

I tried to fetch data from mysql, h2, derby databases but nothing worked. I tried exactly as it was given on w2schools website. But later I thought I would try with Array Function and check with Java JSP page in my AngularJS page calling it.

Below is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <style>
            table, th , td  {
            border: 1px solid grey;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 5px;
            }
            table tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            }
            table tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
                    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
                $http.get("http://localhost:8080/pavanjsp/jsondata.jsp")
               .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my jsondata.jsp below:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSON Data</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <%
                String[] names = { "Alfreds Futterkiste", "B's Beverages", "Berglunds snabbköp", "Blondel père et fils", "Bólido Comidas preparadas", "Bon app'", "Comércio Mineiro" };
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            %>
            <%
                out.print("{ \"records\":[ ");
                for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
                {
                    if(i == (names.length - 1))
                        out.print("{\"Name\":\"" + names[i] + "\"}");
                    else
                        out.print("{\"Name\":\"" + names[i] + "\"}, ");
                }
                out.print(" ] }");
            %>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I even tried putting the index.html as index.jsp and deploying in tomcat. But doesn't works. Even Php code I have tried but not working.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing code to:

```
$scope.names = JSON.parse(response.data).records;
```

If this doesn't work, debug if you receive proper json from server. 
Open some firebug/developer tools ( usually **f12**) and see **network**.

Open page and see **response**. Copy it and paste to some [json validation tool](http://jsonlint.com/). 
If JSON is proper, then something is wrong in angular app, but i see that everything is fine.

Also check in firebug this call, if there is properly CORS configured. 
If you receive result 200 ok, then it's fine.

Also you can use **$log** service to debug your result:

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http,$log)

.then(function (response) {$log.debug('response',response);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, the response is not quite correct from my server. The response from the server is as below:

{ "records":[ {"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste"}, {"Name":"B's Beverages"}, {"Name":"Berglunds snabbköp"}, {"Name":"Blondel père et fils"}, {"Name":"Bólido Comidas preparadas"}, {"Name":"Bon app"}, {"Name":"Comércio Mineiro"} ] }

I tried to make it to JSON type but removing all the extra stuff from my jsp page as in the html stuff din't change the response. And I found the response is in plain text but not JSON.

Can you please check and let me know how to getResponse in JSON format using jsp please.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I got my own answer, and thanks [cyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1651978/cyan) for the help. The issue was with the response, the updated code is as below:

jsaondata.jsp(hosted on tomcat)

```
<%@ page contentType="application/json; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" %>

<%
    String[] names = { "Alfreds Futterkiste", "B's Beverages", "Berglunds snabbköp", "Blondel père et fils", "Bólido Comidas preparadas", "Bon app'", "Comércio Mineiro" };
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
%>
<%
    out.write("{ \"records\":[ ");
    for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
    {
        if(i == (names.length - 1))
            out.write("{\"Name\":\"" + names[i] + "\"}");
        else
            out.write("{\"Name\":\"" + names[i] + "\"}, ");
    }
    out.write(" ] }");
%>
```

angulardata.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<style>
table, th , td  {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/pavanjsp/jsondata.jsp")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So content type must be set to json on server side.